# Excel data reshaping with Python

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a particular spreadsheet which has point of sale data exported feom a sql database.
Im trying to migrate to a new point of sale system and si i need to copy this data that i exported into a csv file into another csv file which has a different format, for example different columns thatvi have to rearrange the original data into.
Im trto do this using python but im failing to find a way to automate this task.
Does anyone have any ideas or any videos on a similar project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/) seems like the python tool for you.

Open up the first CSV file with Pandas as a `DataFrame`, apply any modifications you want, and save as a new CSV file. There is A LOT of documentation and support for Pandas, so I'm sure you can find tutorials on how to do any kind of data reshaping that you want.

Comment: Yeah, what Kike said. Your question is very vague and ambiguous. Try a few things, and when you get stuck on something specific, post a question about that.